# How many Lumens would I have to get in order to create a custom token?

Tags: assets, token, wallets, horizon, token-wallet

I am currently working on creating a custom token on the Stellar network. Like here: https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/how-to-create-a-custom-token-on-stellar-network-in-python-abf8b2f7a6f8

I looked up but couldn't find the metrics which would suggest how many tokens would I meed to hold in order to create a fully functional system containing multiple accounts for transaction and a single anchor to generate tokens. Would the normal norm of holding min:0.5XLM per wallet still hold, or is there any way to modify this. Maybe link multiple accounts to one wallet address.

Suggestions and useful information welcomed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issuing account doesn't actually need anything other than the normal 1 XLM, but any wallet that is going to hold your token will have to add a trust line, and doing that will increase its minimum balance by the base reserve amount (currently 0.5 XLM).  So a Lumen-only wallet has a minimum balance of 1 XLM, but a wallet with your token would need 1.5 XLM.

Comment: Does this include, the Lumens that will be required for transaction fees?

Comment: @ShashwatAditya No, but the transaction fees are minimal, like 0.00001 XLM per operation.  If you sell through the order book, you just need 0.00001 XLM to place the order, and each purchaser needs 0.00001 XLM to buy.  If you sell through some off-chain auction or something, then you'll need 0.00001 XLM per purchaser to send them the tokens they have purchased.

Comment: thanks for the info. One last thing though, is the base reserve amount likely to change?

Comment: It has changed once before to go from 10 to 0.5.  If the price of XLM appreciates significantly, I can imagine validators again reducing the base reserve to ensure accounts are not prohibitively expensive.

Answer (score 0):

You need [Minimum Account Balance](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/fees.html#minimum-account-balance) and some fees to create trustline and send token to Dist account

I think 2XLM is enough

Comment: The total number of XLM required for the entire system would be 2*no. of accounts holding the customized token then.